# Qt QToolTip with crop image

Tags: css, image, qt, tooltip

I'm trying to use a QTreeViewItem to show a cropped image from a .png tileset.

I have a big image divided into 32x32 tiles and want show in the Tooltip only one tile, not the entire image.

I'm using the following:

```
item->setToolTip(0,
    "<html>"
    "<div style=\"32px; height: 32px; overflow: hidden;\">"
        "<img src='data/chars.png' style=\"position: absolute; left:64px;\"/>"
    "</div>"
    "</html>");
```

But the Tooltip text seems to ignore the style and just prints out the entire image.

Is there a way to show only part of a big image in a QToolTip without needing to have several small images instead?

Comment: It has nothing with Qt, but with <img> tag. Use `width=32 height=32` attributes to set image size in html notation. Do not try to use divs, I'm not sure if they are correctly parsed by Qt.

Comment: QToolTip has poor HTML support. I doubt your HTML and CSS can be processed correctly. You can try to use `QImage` class to crop files automatically as you wish.

Comment: But how can I use QImage to draw in a context menu? Some example code would be much appreciated. 

And width, height of <img> tag just downsizes the image, it doesnt crop the image at all, had already tried that first.